# Voice Command Checklist - GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I've looked through the [Voice Command Checklist documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-checklist)

I launch my glassware using a "take a shortcut" voice command.

In string.xml I have:

```
<string name="takeshortcut_text">take a shortcut</string>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.shortcut.activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/takeshortcut_text">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When I deploy to Glass and tap when I see "OK Glass", I see it show up as "take a shortcut" in the menu list of cards.

If I make takeshortcut_text "run a timer", the menu card shows "Run Timer", and if I make it "start a run" it shows "Start Run".

I want similar behavior for my glassware. How can I make it show "Take Shortcut" instead?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking how to have the text displayed in the voice menu different from the text displayed in the touch menu. This is only supported by officially approved voice commands; custom voice commands used during development will display the same string in both menus.

Do go ahead and [submit your voice command requests](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form) using our form if you plan on launching Glassware in the future that would use them.